# WSO2 Identity Server: How to authenticate User?

Tags: authentication, wso2-identity-server

I am using in-memory DB for storing user details in WSO2 Identity server. I create couple of users via UI and now I want to authenticate those user using some external application.

Is there any available WSO2 service which takes User credentials and authenticate based on the details provided? I saw few articles where they mainly talking about User Stores. But there, I think, they directly connect to DB to compare the credentials.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to authenticate a user from Identity Server. Easiest way is that you can call the admin service (SOAP service) for authentication (RemoteUserStoreManagerService/authenticate). Or you can create a OAuth application inside the IS and use resource owner grant type to pass the credentials and authenticate.

You can find admin service related information from here [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Calling+Admin+Services) and password grant related information from here [[2]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Try+Password+Grant)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any available WSO2 service which takes User credentials and
>   authenticate based on the details provided?

I believe we've misused the Token API service ( /token with password OAuth profile) to request an OAuth code and the WSO2IS effectviely validates the user's credentials.

I suggest your application would stick to some authentication and authorization standards supported by the WSO2IS, such as OAuth 2.0 or SAML.